# Возможно ли заменить процессор в ноутбуке на другой с таким же сокетом?

Tags: сокет, процессор

У меня ноутбук Asus Vivobook X540NA. В нём процессор Intel Celeron N3450. Проц не самый мощный, Хром его сильно грузит, а это мой любимый браузер и для меня это важно, т.к. работаю фронтендщиком.
Как я понял, у него сокет FCBGA1296.
Хочу поменять этот процессор на более мощный с таким же сокетом. Возможно ли это в ноутбуке?
Нужно ли смотреть на что-то ЕЩЁ, кроме сокета?
Если невозможно поменять его на другой проц, можно ли этот разогнать?
Ссылка на страницу на сайте Intel про этот проц: https://www.intel.ru/content/www/ru/ru/products/processors/celeron/n3450.html

Вот ещё процы с этим сокетом. Конечно, мне нравятся те, которые мощнее моего и в бенчмарках себя лучше показывают:
https://amd-intel-cpu-benchmark.com/cpu-socket/FCBGA1296

Хочу поменять на самый мощный проц из этого списка: Intel Pentium J4205
https://amd-intel-cpu-benchmark.com/cpu/Intel-Pentium-J4205-@-1.50-GHz_a726a624

Возможно ли это?
Меня смущает то, что у N3450 TDP = 6w, а у Pentium J4205 TDP = 10W.
Это значит, что они несовместимы?

Comment: Вам необходимо разобрать ноутбук и посмотреть что там происходит. Если процессор припаян к материнской плате, то вы можете его заменить только припаяв другой. Чаще всего они припаяны, но бывают случаи когда процессор в разъеме, тогда вы можете спокойно его заменить. Стоит учитывать спецификации материнской платы при выборе процессора. Я не хочу но вынужден вас огорчить, в большинстве случаев процессор припаян, потому что так дешевле для производителя.

Comment: я где-то читал, что другой проц в материнке ноута может не приняться, т.к. биос умеет работать только с тем процом, который был изначально в ноуте и он типа по айди как-то это определяет. Такое может быть?

Comment: очень в этом сомневаюсь, хотя все возможно. вы можете посмотреть с каким процессором ваш ноутбук выпускался, на такой и поменять. вот вам пример видео, где мастер перепаивает процессор. [ссылка](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xdo3OLNkWvc), стоит учитывать то что я не несу ответственность, вы все будете делать на свой страх и риск. чтобы иметь гарантию обратитесь в сервисный центр, который согласится взять на себя ответственность. таким образом вы получите либо ноутбук с лучшим процессором, либо обратно свой рабочий ноутбук. но стоит понимать что это может стоять дорого...

Comment: посмотрите видео полностью, может это даст вам более ясное преставление как это все происходит. Так же от автора видео может быть что-то еще на эту тему, нужно искать.

Comment: замена процессора не сильно скажется на производительности ноутбука. Так что в данном случае вам лучше сменить ноутбук на более современный. Увеличение ОЗУ и установка SSD сильнее скажутся на производительности, чем процессор

Comment: @skorpions2000 BIOS действительно совместим только с соответствующими процессорами. Если новый процессор попытаться запустить на старом BIOS, то этот фокус скорее всего не пройдёт (если семейство процессоров другое).